# How to keep duplicates in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need not to remove duplicates ..

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm=new HashMap();
hm.put(3,"aba");
hm.put(4,"abab");
hm.put(3,"aba");
hm.put(3,"aba");
System.out.println(hm);
```

Is there any way to keep duplicates in HashMap ? If not what should I do(what interface or class should i use ) if I want to do so?

Comment: You are not really removing those duplicates, you are overwriting them. If you want several different values for one key, you can create a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` for example... How does your desired result look?

Comment: Whole point of a `Map` is to keep *pairs* of keys and values. If you need multiple values per key, your map entry has to contain a `Collection<V>` as its value.

Comment: desired result: `aba aba aba abab`  but i need to sort the key

Comment: @Shoukhin78 I updated the answer with the ``sort``.

Comment: @Majed Badawi I want to solve a problem (with hashmap ) in codeforce . I thing If I use your approach time complexity will increase and also more  memory needed.

Comment: @Shoukhin, how do you know the time complexity is going to increase?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov here i mentioned you where i face difficulties while using Hashmap . Codeforces round #486 Question B.Substring sort. What i thing to solve this problem ? =>.In this problem i want solve the problem bellow this approach ...I to put string and their size.and keep the key into an array and sort the array and i took a loop form index 0 to n-1 and finally checked whether i th  string is i+1th substring or not then print ans .(YES/NO)

Comment: @Shoukhin78, I don't know what that "codeforces question" is, so describing how you solving it tells me nothing of value. Ask a question, describe what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I understand that maybe I cannot tell properly with a few word where I stuck.  Thats why I mentioned you  the question and my solving approach.

Comment: I can't comment on your approach because I have no idea what are you trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` cannot have multiple elements with the same `key`. Try using an `ArrayList` instead:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
    private int num;
    private String name;
    public Item(int num, String name) {
        this.setNum(num);
        this.setName(name);
    }
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [num=" + num + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item other) {
        return this.num-other.num;
    }
}
```

```
List<Item> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Item(3,"aba"));
list.add(new Item(4,"abab"));
list.add(new Item(3,"aba"));
list.add(new Item(3,"aba"));
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Output:

```
[Item [num=3, name=aba], Item [num=3, name=aba], Item [num=3, name=aba], Item [num=4, name=abab]]
```

Comment: It's too early to suggest using just a list. We don't know how the map is used in general application.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov We do [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63740278/how-to-keep-duplicates-in-hashmap#comment112713747_63740278): *"desired result: `aba aba aba abab` but i need to sort the key"*

Comment: Still, it generally doesn't answer the question of keeping duplicate values in Map.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov "cannot have multiple elements with the same key"

Comment: @MajedBadawi, exactly. That doesn't mean you can't store values or keep track of number of duplicates, but the value is going to be something other than `String` in that case.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov here i mentioned you where i face difficulties while using Hashmap . Codeforces round #486 Question B.Substring sort. What i thing to solve this problem ? =>.In this problem i want solve the problem bellow this approach ...I to put string and their size.and keep the key into an array and sort the array and i took a loop form index 0 to n-1 and finally checked whether i th string is i+1th substring or not then print ans .(YES/NO)